# ObservableCollection and setting values

Tags: c#, observablecollection

Is this.

```
    private ObservableCollection<String> _Col;
    public ObservableCollection<String> Col
    {
        get
        {
            return _Col;
        }
        set
        {
            _Col = value;
        }
    }
```

the same as this

```
public ObservableCollection<String> Col { get; set }
```

using col.add("stringvaribleorsomething") they would both result in col being a collection of items?

Comment: I suppose this was a typo, but in your setter it should be `_Col = value;`

Comment: You seem to be confusing two different issues. The use of a backing variable or auto property doesn't change the semantics of the `.Add` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly - yes. But look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) about auto-implemented properties in C#

Comment: Thanks for sharing this article, im not sure i understand. what i think its trying to tell me is that if at any stage i have to modify the values it would be difficult with the second example so it is best to use the first example.

Comment: @New Bee you can also take a look at the following. It would give some sharp explanation. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523548/why-we-need-properties-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to both `getter` and `setter` methods like that, yes it is the same.But if you want to make your property read only,or set your property value depends on some condition you should use the first one.

Also the second one is called `auto-implemented property`.You can see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)