# What does getters & setters method do in Java, how are they different from normal methods, and why is the getMethod sometime missing?

Tags: java

I am new to Java.

1. Can any one explain **what the getters and setters method do?**
2. where we must use getters setters method and **how it differ from the normal method?**
3. And i saw some coding having only setter method so here **why getters method not declared?**

   ```
   private String wheel;

   /**
    * @param wheel the wheel to set
    */
   public void setWheel(String wheel) {
       this.wheel = wheel;
   }
   public void rotate() {
       System.out.println(wheel+"rotated");
   }
   ```

Comment: He is asking 1) **how they differ** from normal methods, and 2) Why the above code is **missing a get-method**. Neither of which is answered in the linked question.

Comment: (this post was closed as a duplicate of [What is the point of setters and getters in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461598/what-is-the-point-of-setters-and-getters-in-java)).

Comment: Tim Post, as there are only 4 voters to close, I'm assuming you closed this as a moderator. Was that really the right thing to do? I can only see how the related question answer one out of the three question @BoomirajP asked here.

Answer (score 4):

> ***Can any one explain what the getters and setters method do?***

Get-methods and set-methods help in [encapsulating data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29). That's all. Instead of writing

```
object.wheel = new Wheel(5);
// ...
object.wheel.rotate();
```

you do

```
object.setWheel(new Wheel(5));
// ...
object.getWheel().rotate();
```

This gives you better control of the update of the field. You could for instance:

- Throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the wheel doesn't fit.
- Compute or load a new wheel on the fly in the `getWheel`-method.
- Let other object *listen* for wheel-updates

etc.

> ***where we must use getters setters method and how it differ from the normal method?***

You don't *have* to use getters and setters, it's just good practice.

Technically speaking getters and setters are **no different** from normal methods. They just have a specific (simple) purpose.

> ***And i saw some coding having only setter method so here why getters method not declared?***

The author of the class simply didn't want to expose the wheel-object to the user. The reasons for this may vary.

Comment: Now if Java *really* helped with Encapsulation and let Getters/Setters be indistinguishable from normal "property access"... :-/

Comment: Yep. Scala for instance obeys the [uniform access principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle) quite nicely :-)

Comment: Unfortunately switching the implementation from direct to getter/setter swill still break binary compatibility :( Also an issue with .NET though...

Answer (score 0):

Getters expose the fields. So you saw code with only setters- that makes it write only, with no read privileges. Setter => Write, Getter => Read.

These methods are typically very simple, and you can choose to handle errors in them too.

Normally you would have a private field, and either a getter or a setter (or both) to access it.

Comment: Setters doesn't expose the field.