# what does this line says...?

Tags: java

Even though I have done bit of coding in java, I'm still finding it hard to understand this basic concept. When I was going through a book I came across this line,

> `main( )` must be declared as `public`, since it must be called
>   by code outside of its class when the program is started.

What does the author mean by saying **code outside of its class**?

Comment: @MByD.. i'm not asking who is calling it.. i know JVM calls it.. but i did't know code Outside means that its the JVM..

Comment: As the OP says, this is a question about **the interpretation of this particular sentence** in a book, not whether or not it is actually the JVM that calls the method. (It's even evident from the title of the question.)

Comment: @aioobe - I maybe got confused because of the question "which code is calling it..?". anyway, sorry, it just sounded like a duplicate to me.

Comment: @MByD.. and people just followed you by not even reading the question...:)

Comment: @MByD, no prob... actually the question is slightly ambiguous. a bit frustrated as this is the second question that [gets closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088814/what-does-getters-setters-method-do-in-java-how-are-they-different-from-normal/7088834#7088834) today, for poor reasons (imo) :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ***what do the author mean by saying code outside of its class.. which code is calling it..?***

It is the JVM that calls the method, so, yes, "outside of its class" should in this case be interpreted as "by the JVM".

Technically speaking, the JVM is not a part of the class containing the main method, thus the method has to be public for it to call it.

Comment: @aioobe.. you mean to say code outside indirectly means its the JVM...?

Comment: Yes, that would be my interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

Directly JVM is calling this class without creating instance of this class so it is static.

when you run that class under the cover your OS receives this command

```
java YourMainClass
```

here java is an executable that your OS knows where it is and YourMainClass is the argument to the `java` it loads the class and searches & invokes the main method

Since it is JVM calling so `public` , Since it isn't creating any instance of the object it is `static`

Answer (score 1):

The `main()` method is invoked by the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Another class not in this package or the JVM itself.

Comment: Not true, main is a public method like anyone else. It's the programmer's choice to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The main function is the entry point of your program. If this function is not public and static your program can not be started.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in the low level stuff check this: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/execution.doc.html